# Tool to remove clicking sounds in audio recording due to clipping (Android or Windows)

Tags: audio, music, audio-recording, music-production, audio-editing

Please recommend Android or Windows software (or a web-app) that will remove clicking sounds from recordings of band practice sessions due to the peak audio levels being too loud.

I realize that it won't sound perfect, but I'm looking for something that will reduce or eliminate the clicks that occur every time the mic was overblown during the recordings.

The files are currently in M4A format, but I can convert them to any other format first, if needed.

I prefer gratis software, but anything up to about 5 euros/dollars is fine.

Open-source is great, but not required.

Portable (no installer) tools are preferred if it's Windows software, but it's not a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

[Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/):

- has a very effective filter for noise removal
- Supports import/export of AC3, **M4A**/M4R & with the optional FFmpeg library
- Is free, gratis & open source
- Is available for Windows/Mac/Linux

Can do a lot more.
[image]